# CMake INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES entries get decorated

Tags: cmake

I recently did some CMake cleanup on a library I have, the main change being that instead of exporting my targets to a config file directly. At the same time I wanted to move adding the target to the toplevel CMakeLists.txt and then just add sources to that single target as I recurse down into subdirectories.

So I have the toplevel `CMakelists.txt` that contains:

```
add_library(Foo "")
add_library(Bar::Foo ALIAS Foo)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

in `src` the CMakeLists.txt has

```
add_subdirectory(Buz)
add_subdirectory(Fuz)
```

in `Fuz` the `CMakeLists.txt` has

```
target_sources(Foo
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FooSource.hpp>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/FooSource.hpp> 
  PRIVATE 
    FooSource.cpp  
)

target_include_directories(Foo
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}>    
)

target_link_libraries(Foo
  PUBLIC
    Bar::Buz # target from first sub dir add...eventually to be merged in like manner
  PRIVATE
    avcodec  
    avformat
    avutil
    swscale
)
```

Before the change the resulting `FooConfig.cmake` that would be installed would contain these lines:

```
set_target_properties(Foo::Foo PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/klv_parser;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/frame_source"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "\$<LINK_ONLY:avcodec>;\$<LINK_ONLY:avformat>;\$<LINK_ONLY:avutil>;\$<LINK_ONLY:swscale>;\$<LINK_ONLY:Foo::foo_common>"
  INTERFACE_SOURCES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/klv_parser/KlvParser.hpp;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/frame_source/FrameSource.hpp"
```

where the `LINK_ONLY` libraries are ones I listed as `PRIVATE` in a `target_link_libraries`. However since the change, these private libraries have been decorated with a seemingly random hex number:

```
set_target_properties(Foo::Foo PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/klv_parser;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/frame_source"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "\$<LINK_ONLY:avcodec::@<0x2aaeb30>>;\$<LINK_ONLY:avformat::@<0x2aaeb30>>;\$<LINK_ONLY:avutil::@<0x2aaeb30>>;\$<LINK_ONLY:swscale::@<0x2aaeb30>>;\$<LINK_ONLY:Foo::foo_common::@<0x2aaeb30>>"
  INTERFACE_SOURCES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/klv_parser/KlvParser.hpp;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/Foo/frame_source/FrameSource.hpp"
)
```

Libraries in the `PUBLIC` section of `target_link_libraries` are not decorated--only ones in the `PRIVATE` section are.

I've been able to narrow it down to moving the `add_library` command to a higher level directory.  i.e. if my `CMakeLists.txt` in the `Fuz` directory has:

```
add_library(Foo "")
add_library(Bar::Foo ALIAS Foo)

target_sources(Foo
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FooSource.hpp>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/FooSource.hpp> 
  PRIVATE 
    FooSource.cpp  
)

target_include_directories(Foo
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}>    
)

target_link_libraries(Foo
  PUBLIC
    Bar::Buz # target from first sub dir add...eventually to be merged in like manner
  PRIVATE
    avcodec  
    avformat
    avutil
    swscale
)
```

(and no `add_library` commands are in the top level `CMakeLists.txt`) they all works as it should. But if the only change I make is to move the two lines

```
add_library(Foo "")
add_library(Bar::Foo ALIAS Foo)
```

to either the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` or even the one in `src` then this weird decoration occurs.  To me this really seems like a bug in `CMake`, but maybe not?

I'm using CMake 3.15.5 on Ubuntu 18.04. Full minimal example is here: https://github.com/jasonbeach/cmake_bug.git

Comment: "There was some other miscellaneous cleanup as well, which I wouldn't think would make a difference." - In other words, you want us to **guess** which action in your "miscellaneous cleanup" procedure causes the difference in the generated Config file? Moreover, we should guess without viewing your code (since you show only a single line of your code). This is not how Stack Overflow works. For being able to help you, we expect you to provide [mcve].

Comment: I'm working on that, but it's easier said than done...I was hoping someone would know the conditions that would cause `configure_package_config_file` to decorate the libraries in that way.

Comment: Well, it is possible that someone knows the "key phrase" in the generated file. But there are far more people who could tell you that your `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong... assuming you show that `CMakeLists.txt`. "which causes downstream libraries to complain that they can't be found." - Please, show the **exact error message**. I don't mean that error message will replace the absent code, but it could help somehow.

Comment: Still working on the minimum example, but it turns out it appears to be something else in the cleanup I was doing.. I've updated the question

Comment: Not related to the question, but a heads up: You should almost never have PUBLIC `target_sources`, and your case isn't one of them. PUBLIC sources, just like other PUBLIC target properties, are transitively inherited by every target linking to it. So if you open your project in an IDE that has a view that groups source files by target (e.g. Visual Studio) these headers will show up in every target that directly or indirectly links against Foo.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug within CMake.  I was originally using CMake 3.15.5 and in the course of troubleshooting, updated to CMake 3.19.6 and it started working as it should. It appears to have been fixed somewhere in there.